# TIMEOUT WHILE CONNECTING TO SERVER

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

When I use Wi-Fi to upload code through VS Code, it shows the following error. But if I use mobile network, it works.

```
[error] Error: Timeout while connecting to server
    at Timeout._onTimeout (c:\Users\faraz\.vscode\extensions\liximomo.sftp-1.12.9\dist\extension.js:70:109790)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*upload code through VS Code*"? It seems you are using an extension? It seems your WiFi network is either slow on uploads or has restrictions on what can be accessed. In any case, this doesn't look like a programming problem.

Comment: "upload code through VS Code" means I am using sftp. You are right this is not a programming problem. It happens only on wifi, maybe it has a restriction on upload code. Thank you.